# Mojave 10.14.4 update causes mail passwords not to work

Tags: mail.app, email, password

After 10.14.4 my hotmail and ntlworld mail accounts will not login. Have checked passwords and theses are the same ones that still work on the iPad and iPhone . But re-entering on iMac says "unable to verify account name or password".
The question "mail for mac will not accept my password" has an answer about "app-specific passwords" and talks about 2-level authentication .
What should I do ?
Do I have to make new passwords for hotmail and ntlworld?
Or is there a bug fix coming?
Help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's no bugfix coming because this isn't a bug.  Take a look at [this Apple email configuration site](https://support.apple.com/mail-settings-lookup) and make sure you're using the correct settings.  There's also links there to help you properly add your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Apple Mail to collect your mail?

One solution that seems to work for many is to delete these accounts entirely then go to Sys Prefs > Internet Accounts and re-establish/enter them.  That's why I did and it worked just fine for me (and for others).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and did not want to delete accounts.
I solved the problem by changing my app password in Keychain Access! Keychain Access had an old password stored there.